# Run an external program as a "calculator" with php

Tags: php, system-calls

I try to launch an app like "calc" or "notepad" on my pc, using PHP:

```
<?php
echo "Start ..." ;
system("calc");?>
```

However when I launch nothing happens.
I followed this simple tutorial:
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GNbTRJHbC4Q
but no program is running as planned.

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: I tried in local and work, which php version do you have?

Comment: Hello, I have PHP version 7.2.18 and my local server is wamp server

Comment: It makes no sense do this in a webpage context. PHP runs on the server machine, so any command you execute will be executed on the server, not on the client machine where you are viewing the page. (If, for testing / development purposes, you're using the same machine for both client and server it might be able to work, but that's just an accident of your environment, and it doesn't reflect the real world).

Comment: I don't know what that tutorial is really trying to achieve - it would make no sense to open a calculator on a remote server. (other non-interactive apps like ping or something, sure, because your PHP program can just read the results back, but not GUI apps, that is not useful). And why do **you** want to open your calculator via a web page??

Comment: the opening of the calculator is only used for test purposes.
I actually think that if I can open a calculator, I can open a java file "test.class" and interact with this file by the CMD so that it can send information about a pc to a BDD.
When I have finished developing the application I will then launch the.jar files so that the application runs in graphical mode.
That's why I'm actually trying to open a simple calculator with a cmd.

Comment: So really you want to execute a Java program? Ok, that could work. But " I will then launch the.jar files so that the application runs in graphical mode" won't work if you run that via PHP, on your server. You'd have the same issue as the calculator example.

Comment: You need to understand that the program will be executed o the server, not on client, so you will not be able to retrieve information about the client PC as you want.

Comment: the data recovery and sending are done on the jar file that the client pc will download.
Once downloaded I just try to run this.jar file remotely with php.
It is the program that will communicate with the database.

Comment: "Once downloaded I just try to run this.jar file remotely with php."...that isn't possible. Think about it - do you really want it to be possible for some remote server to execute programs on your PC?? That would be a hacker's dream, and everyone else's nightmare. I don't think you have really considered the wider implications of what you are suggesting. It's impossible to do what you suggest, because it would create a huge security problem. (It used to be possible to do this using things like ActiveX, but that was withdrawn precisely because it kept being exploited by criminals and hackers.)

Comment: You can tell the user to download the jar file, and then you can give them instructions about how to execute it (you might need multiple sets of instructions for Windows, Mac, Linux). That's as far as you can go. You can't actually cause the program to execute directly. That is the user's decision.

Comment: Open a Command Prompt window and type `calc` see what happens. Know that the command will be executed on the server not on the pc of the person visiting your website